# Empty table row when location id changes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data table which contains hundreds of records and each record has a location id.
What I am trying to do is echo out all the records with a line break when the location id changes.

The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT LocationID, deviceName, companyname, record_ID,location, location,orderby FROM FIDS_Hardware WHERE deviceTypeCode = 5 AND monitor = 1 ORDER BY hotelID ASC, orderby ASC
```

The code I am using to produce the table may look strange but it is how I want it to work.

```
$Limit2 = 5;
$Count2 = 0;
echo "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='2'>"; 
                  
while ($row_ConfMon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ConfMon)) { 
    $locationid = $row_ConfMon['hotelID'];
    $RoomNo2 = $row_ConfMon['deviceName'];
    $companyname = $row_ConfMon['companyname'];
    $recordID = $row_ConfMon['record_ID'];
    $location = $row_ConfMon['location'];
    $DownDate = date("d-m-y", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);
    $DownTime = date("H:i", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);

    if($row_ConfMon['NoDevice'] == 1) {
        if($Count2 < $Limit2) {
                            
            if($Count2 == 0) {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewpurple\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div> <div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
         } else {
            $Count2 = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr><a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewpurple\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div><div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        }
        $Count2++;
    } elseif($row_ConfMon['MobileDisplay'] == 1 && $row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) {
        if($Count2 < $Limit2) {
            if($Count2 == 0) {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewamber\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div> <div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        } else {
            $Count2 = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr><a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewamber\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div><div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        }
        $Count2++;
    } elseif($row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) {
        if($Count2 < $Limit2) {
            if($Count2 == 0) {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewred\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div> <div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        } else {
            $Count2 = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr><a href=\"confmon.php\" target=\"_self\"><td class=\"roomviewred\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div><div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        }
        $Count2++;
    } else {
        if($Count2 < $Limit2) {
            if($Count2 == 0) {
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            echo "<td class=\"roomviewgreen\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div><div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td>";
        } else {
            $Count2 = 0;
            echo "</tr><tr><td class=\"roomviewgreen\" valign=\"top\"><div class=\"coltitle\"><a href=\"confmon_hist.php?recordID=$recordID\" target=\"_self\">$companyname</a></div><div class=\"confmontime2\">$location<br />$RoomNo2<br /></div><span class=\"confmontime\">$DownDate<br /><div class=\"confmontime2\">$DownTime</div><br /></span></td></a>";
        }
        $Count2++;  
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

I currently echo all the records into a table but I would like to start a new line in the table when the location id changes, like.

[image]

This is what the output currently looks like.

[image]

This is what I would like it to look like.

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: How are you echo-ing your result? Please add that code. If it is a foreach, you could simply check the current $item->id vs. a the previous id. If true, do a blank row.

Comment: Most things are possible if you write sufficicient code, yes. So where you are stuck? You forgot to ask a meaningful question or explain a specific issue within your attempt. Therefore we don't know level of help you need, and we've got no context within which to suggest a solution or identify any kind of problem. See also [ask] and [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Comment: It should just be a case of looping through the data, and keeping track of what Location ID was used in the previous row, so you can compare it to the current one, and then decide whether to add an extra line or not. As a general concept ("do something different on the next line depending on the contents of the previous one") this is far from a new or unusual scenario. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Thanks for the update. So what happens when you run this code currently? Have you tried my suggestion? And where is the $Limit2 variable defined, and what's its purpose?  Is that what's causing your issue? P.S. You have a lot of redundant, duplicated stuff in those `echo`s...most of it is repeated, the only thing being varied seems to be one class name, and whether you use an extra `</tr><tr>` or not - you could remove a lot of redundancy and make the code clearer by just setting those strings and then concatenating them at the end into one which contains the remaining, fixed content.

Comment: Also where is $Count2 defined initially? That is also missing. Provide a [mre] of the issue please, and a clear explanation of how the current behaviour differs from your expectation, based on your debugging efforts so far. Remember we can't easily run the code since we don't have your database available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just be a case of looping through the data, and keeping track of what Location ID was used in the previous row, so you can compare it to the current one, and then decide whether to add an extra line or not.

P.S. There's also a lot of repeated code in your original, so I took the liberty of removing the repetition - changing the logic around where you create new rows to just do that once, and also using variables to represent what changes in the different `echo` statements (which is only a class name, and the addition of an extra table row) so you only need to state most of the HTML once, and lastly refactoring it to get rid of all the escape characters which were cluttering it up too.

Oh an your HTML table was technically malformed because you didn't put any `<td>` cells into the row.

For that reason, let's take this in stages. This first version is equivalent to producing the output that you have now:

```
$colLimit = 5;
$colCount = 1;
$tableHTML = "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='2'>".PHP_EOL;
                  
while ($row_ConfMon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ConfMon))
{ 
    $locationid = $row_ConfMon['hotelID'];
    $RoomNo2 = $row_ConfMon['deviceName'];
    $companyname = $row_ConfMon['companyname'];
    $recordID = $row_ConfMon['record_ID'];
    $location = $row_ConfMon['location'];
    $DownDate = date("d-m-y", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);
    $DownTime = date("H:i", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);
    
    $rowHTML = "";
    $className = "";

    if ($colCount == 1)
    {
        $rowHTML .= "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    if($row_ConfMon['NoDevice'] == 1) $className = "roomviewpurple";
    elseif($row_ConfMon['MobileDisplay'] == 1 && $row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) $className = "roomviewamber";
    elseif($row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) $className = "roomviewred";
    else $className = "roomviewgreen";
    
    $linkHTML = '<td><a href="confmon.php" target="_self"><td class="'.$className.'" valign="top"><div class="coltitle"><a href="confmon_hist.php?recordID='.$recordID.'" target="_self">'.$companyname.'</a></div> <div class="confmontime2">'.$location.'<br />'.$RoomNo2.'<br /></div><span class="confmontime">'.$DownDate.'<br /><div class="confmontime2">'.$DownTime.'</div><br /></span></td></a></td>'.PHP_EOL;
    $rowHTML .= $linkHTML;

    if ($colCount == $colLimit)
    {
        $rowHTML .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
        $colCount = 1;
    }
    else $colCount++;
    
    $tableHTML .= $rowHTML;
}

//tidy up end of table
if (substr($tableHTML, -4) != "</tr>") $tableHTML .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
$tableHTML .= "</table>";

//output the table
echo $tableHTML;
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/HQqL3

---

Now this next one should do the job for starting a new row when the location field has changed. As you can see, I've added a variable to keep track of the location ID from the previous row, so we can compare it, and also changed the point where it decides whether to end the row and reset the column count - it's delayed until we're processing the start of the next row, so there's the opportunity to compare the location IDs. As per your comment below, it also adds another row for spacing, when changing location ID:

```
$colLimit = 5;
$colCount = 1;
$tableHTML = "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='2'>".PHP_EOL;
$prevLocationID = ""; //to keep track of the location on the preceding data item
                  
while ($row_ConfMon = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ConfMon))
{ 
    $locationid = $row_ConfMon['hotelID'];
    $RoomNo2 = $row_ConfMon['deviceName'];
    $companyname = $row_ConfMon['companyname'];
    $recordID = $row_ConfMon['record_ID'];
    $location = $row_ConfMon['location'];
    $DownDate = date("d-m-y", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);
    $DownTime = date("H:i", $row_ConfMon['uptime']);
    
    $rowHTML = "";
    $className = "";

    if ($colCount == $colLimit || $prevLocationID != $locationid)
    {
        $rowHTML .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
        if ($prevLocationID != $locationid) $rowHTML .= "<tr></tr>.PHP_EOL";
        $colCount = 1;
    }
    else $colCount++;

    if ($colCount == 1)
    {
        $rowHTML .= "<tr>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    if($row_ConfMon['NoDevice'] == 1) $className = "roomviewpurple";
    elseif($row_ConfMon['MobileDisplay'] == 1 && $row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) $className = "roomviewamber";
    elseif($row_ConfMon['messageCount'] == 2) $className = "roomviewred";
    else $className = "roomviewgreen";
    
    $linkHTML = '<td><a href="confmon.php" target="_self"><td class="'.$className.'" valign="top"><div class="coltitle"><a href="confmon_hist.php?recordID='.$recordID.'" target="_self">'.$companyname.'</a></div> <div class="confmontime2">'.$location.'<br />'.$RoomNo2.'<br /></div><span class="confmontime">'.$DownDate.'<br /><div class="confmontime2">'.$DownTime.'</div><br /></span></td></a></td>'.PHP_EOL;
    $rowHTML .= $linkHTML;

    $prevLocationID = $locationid; //set "previous" location ID as the current one, ready for processing the next data item
    $tableHTML .= $rowHTML;

}

//tidy up end of table
if (substr($tableHTML, -4) != "</tr>") $tableHTML .= "</tr>".PHP_EOL;
$tableHTML .= "</table>";

//output the table
echo $tableHTML;
```

Live demo: https://3v4l.org/KRiU1

Comment: I don't know how to thank for all your time. It does exactly what I was trying to achieve. Now I can study code that works and learn from it, Many thanks again.

Comment: Hi How could I put a blank row or row break after each of the $locationid changes giving a space between each group of record belonging to $locationid. Again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Just add an extra row when that condition specifically is met. I've updated the answer and the demo, please take a look

Comment: I am getting a line of .PHP_EOL at the top of the table::  <tr>
                                    <table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='2'>
                                </tr>
                                <tr></tr>
                                .PHP_EOL

Comment: and I can't see where that is coming from.

Comment: just found what was causing the line of PHP_EOL. But I am still on getting a blank row separating the rows when the locationis changes. Any idea's?

Comment: I don't know...my demo produces an extra tr in the right place, as you can see. If it doesn't render as expected, maybe try putting some nominal content into it, e.g. `if ($prevLocationID != $locationid) $rowHTML .= "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>.PHP_EOL";`. That might force it to add some real spacing.

Comment: That did it. Looks the way I wanted it to look. If your ever in Warwickshire let me know, I owe your a beer.

Comment: Happy to help. Hopefully the code makes sense and you can see how it does the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do the space insertion in your PHP code -- via a `foreach` loop, for example -- rather than in the SQL. Is it possible to do this with SQL? Yes, but for something presentation-related like this, I would suggest just cycling through the rows and adding the empty `<tr>` tags on the PHP end. It will almost certainly be a lot cleaner, and it keeps the correct behaviors on the correct layers of the application.

Comment: Hi All, I have added the code that produces the table, it may look strange but it works for the project.

Comment: Also added more in the SQL statement

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include $Limit and $Count2 at the top  of the script when I was copying the code into the post. Sorry for that. $Limit is used to determine the number of columns across the page. I have been trying to find a way to loop through the data array but I am stuck on how to do this using the locationID.

Comment: @DCJones can you try and reply on the right thread next time, I've only just noticed this :-)

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for that.